# keyboard not working on sl4a interpreter on samsung galaxy y s5360

Tags: scripting, sl4a

The soft keyboard is not working on my mobile in the sl4a environment. The keyboard is present there but on taping the keys nothing happens. Please kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grabbing a different keyboard off the [Play Store](http://play.google.com/), such as [Hacker's Keyboard (which is good for this kind of thing)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard)